# Findstr output formatting

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I have many log files where i want to extract specific text from it and copy it to a new file with FINDSTR command,

E.g: I have log files called 1.log and I need to extract all the numbers that start with `N66666` lines in the log files that looks like:

```
22220473400664->473400664
 01210260222->01210260222->N8888801210260222 
 01278448231->01278448231->N6666601278448231
 01286799109->01286799109->N8888801286799109
```

I tried:

```
findstr /s /i "\<N66666.*" *.* > results.txt
```

but the result was copying the whole lines starting with `N6666` to results.txt, where I need the numbers only to be copied to results.txt.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetstring=N66666"
FOR /f "tokens=3delims=>" %%a IN ('findstr /s /i "%targetstring%.*" *.*') DO ECHO(%%a

GOTO :EOF
```

This might be usable - you are very short on information provided.

It relies on your required data being the in the string after the second `>` character in the lines required; I've not redirected the result to a file as that's a trivial modification.

---

In the light of further information:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "targetstring=N66666"
SET /a ltargetstring=0
SET "output=%targetstring%"
:dtslp
SET /a ltargetstring+=1
SET "output=%output:~1%"
IF DEFINED output GOTO dtslp
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /s /i "%targetstring%.*" *.*') DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:>= !"
 SET "line=!line:<= !"
 SET "line=!line:"=!"
 CALL :process !line!
)

GOTO :EOF
:process
SET "output=%1"
IF NOT DEFINED output GOTO :EOF 
CALL SET "output=%%output:~0,%ltargetstring%%%"
IF /i "%output%" neq "%targetstring%" GOTO miss
SET "output=%1"
CALL SET "output=%%output:~%ltargetstring%%%"
ECHO(%output%

:miss
SHIFT
GOTO process
```

The information you have provided should have been edited into your question, not posted as comments.

You have not replied to the point that the original solution relied on "your required data being the in the string after the second > character in the lines required" you've stated that the output "number" that is required is that between the "N66666" and the next space (or, given the data provided, end-of-line; there is no example where there is extra data on the line beyond the required string)

So there's still a lot of guesswork.

This process reads each line that contains the target string from the files, then replaces ech ">" and "<" in tose strings with a space and removes any <kbd>"</kbd>

The resultant string is then processed using standard separtors by matching each substring found to the target string using the substring methodology applying the length of the target string calculated on initialisation into `ltargetstring`.

If the first part of the string found matches the target, the remainder of the string is extracted and `echo`ed and the process repeated until there are no more parameters to `:process`.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply, i have a folder that contains many log files, i need to read from all those log files all numbers that start with N66666 and cut the N66666 from it, and redirect result to an output file, in the above example it should get the N6666601278448231 and cut of the leading N66666 and put result as 01278448231 in the output file, if it is too complicated to cut off the leading N66666 it is ok to have the result in output file as N6666601278448231 i can cut it off manually later.

Comment: One more thing there could be text after the N6666601278448231 so when extracting required text i need not to take till end of line and that number is length is not fixed so it should start extracting from N666666 and stop on the 1st space.